# Computer has become very slow and unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, performance, browser, updates, virus-removal

I have noticed recently that my computer has become very slow and unresponsive, and I'm not really sure why...

I have run scans using AVG Antivirus 2013 (with the latest definitions) and Ad-Aware (with the latest definitions), but neither of those have found any viruses or other problems...

I have noticed occasionally, that when opening a new tab in my browser, or searching for something directly from the address bar, sometimes it will come up with a 'Nation' search, even though my default search engine is Google.

I am wondering if this is a browser hijack? I've had problems with a browser hijack before... can't remember what it was called, but it used to appear every time I opened a new tab, or searched for something directly from the address bar- Nation only seems to occur occasionally (but it shouldn't happen at all- I have no idea what it is or where it's come from).

When I previously had the problem with the browser hijack, people advised me to use several programs to try and clear it up:

- Hitman Pro
- MalwareBytes Anti Malware
- SecurityCheck
- AdwCleaner
- Spybot
- HijackThis
- ComboFix
- rKill
- CCleaner

They seemed to do the trick at the time, but I don't know how to use them myself to try and clear this up, and some of these were trial versions and have now expired...

Another thing that I thought could be the cause, is that Windows has been updating itself, and has recently tried to install a Windows 7 service pack several times when shutting down. However, every time it has done this, and the update has started configuring itself when I've turned the computer back on, the configuration (or update, or whatever) has failed, and it has had to 'revert changes'... Could this be why my computer is now running so slow? If so, how do I speed it up again, and stop Windows from trying to install the service pack, or how can I ensure that the service pack installation is successful?

Does anyone have any ideas why my computer has become so slow and unresponsive, and how I can speed it up again? I have tried de-fragmenting, and the other system tools, but these don't seem to have helped.

Also, how can I get rid of this Nation search?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: All the programs you listed should be as simply as just running the scan mechanic. Have you tried to delete you browser profiles and all said browser extensions? Why have you not release a Service Pack release 2 years ago?  You need to repair your installation before you will be able to install the Service Pack.

Comment: The programs I have mentioned will run... but since some of them were trial versions, some won't, or won't remove any threats if they find any... Sorry, what do you mean with the Service Pack? It has been trying to install for several months, but keeps failing every time I install it- should it have been updated two years ago? Maybe it was, and this is another service pack? I can't remember that long ago...

Comment: follow this http://pastebin.com/at7DyJxm. Run the command before the slowness occurs, minimize the CMD Window and when you have the issue, restore the cmd and capture 30 -60s of the slowness and then press a key to stop logging

Comment: @someone2088 - Windows 7 Service Pack 1 was release over 3 years ago.  Its very odd you are still trying to install it.  In other words this Service Pack problem isn't a new problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't install so much anti-malware to get rid of the malware you have.

MalwareBytes is one of the best apps for this; especially for people who don't know how to manage their own computers.  Here's a nice [How To](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/how-to-use-malwarebytes-anti-malware-tutorial) if you need help learning how to use it. (**Update**: Also, malwarebytes is extremely lightweight and free for home users.  The difference between the free and paid version is the paid version will actively monitor your system and protect, whereas the free version will only scan your system when you tell it to; in short, proactive verses reactive protection)

Second, your computer is hosed.  The registry is probably corrupt from all the malware and or bad attempts to install legitimate patches.  This happens from time to time, either due to a bad order of installations for the patches or because it's patch Tuesday and it's Microsoft.  It happens way more than it should (it should never happen, but it does, because it's Microsoft).  This is preventing you from installing that service pack or patch that you want (also, to the guy who says SP2 is available; no, it's not--not officially anyway, and probably never, according to a quick Google search).

You're better off backing up your data to a USB hard drive, formatting your system and starting from scratch.  It'll save you time and headaches, as rebuilding a PC can take 2-4 hours, whereas constantly troubleshooting malware and registry issues can go on forever.

Comment: I don't see a single person who said Windows 7 SP2 exists.  What I said was that it was released 2 years ago plus the fact a bunchered the statement.

Comment: Since MS finally came out with Microsoft Security Essentials I've had a lot less trouble with anti-virus and/or anti-malware being as much (or more) of a problem as the malware it was trying to prevent by just running that and windows firewall, and tossing the rest of it. But I agree that you are at the point of **reinstall from scratch.**